# how can I parse the format by Java

Tags: java, parsing

Is there any API which I can call to parse the following format file?

```
define student {
    full_name     Smith,John
    sex    male
    age      19
    grade      90
    class_number   8.43.1
    reg_hour  5x3
}
```

The file is not in good format. As shown, there are different numbers of spaces and \t between titles and values.

Any advice to parse this format by java? or by Python...

Comment: what kind of filetype is this?  a *.txt , or a *.csv , or what type?

Comment: You could quite easily use string manipulation in any language to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be straight forward in Java using StreamTokenizer:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html

It will skip over all kinds of whitespace, but you'll need to call `eolIsSignificant(true)` as there does not seem to be any other delimiter for the values.

Should look roughly like this (not sure whether one can turn eol significance on and off during parsing):

```
StreamTokenizer tokenizer = new StreamTokenizer(fileInputStream);
tokenizer.wordChars('_', '_');
tokenizer.nextToken(); 
while ("define".equals(tokenizer.sval)) {
  tokenizer.nextToken();
  String recordName = tokenizer.sval;
  if (tokenizer.nextToken() != '{') {
    throw new RuntimeException("'{' expected");
  }
  while (tokenizer.nextToken() != '}') {
    String key = tokenizer.sval;
    tokenizer.nextToken();
    String value = tokenizer.sval;
    tokenizer.eolIsSignificant(true);
    while (tokenizer.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOL &&
           tokenizer.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
      value += " " + tokenizer.sval();  // If this is common, use StringBuilder
    }
    tokenizer.eolIsSignificant(false);
  }
}
```

Comment: Downvoted because when you posted, it was a comment at best. I can't undownvote because you edited within the 5 min grace period.

Comment: I got a problem when there are values contain underscore. 
For example,  
full_name    John Smith
It will be parsed as full and null John Smith. string after underscore is null. I'm confused...

Comment: '_' does not occur in the example -- you'll need to add `tokenizer.wordChars('_', '_')`. I have updated the code accordingly.

Comment: the file may have many kinds of symbols. I have updated my question. How could I handle all of them?

Comment: Should work; you'll need to add the additional characters (including digits) to wordChars and turn off number parsing. Alternatively, you could try a line based approach with line.trim().replaceAll(...) for whitespace normalization.

Answer (score 0):

```
There are various ways of parsing text. You can use ant which best fits to u

String.split methods
StringTokenizer and  StreamTokenizer classes
Scanner class
Pattern and Matcher classes, which implement regular expressions
for the most complex parsing tasks, you can use tools such as JavaCC
```